# Getters for reference type variables c++

Tags: c++

```
std::vector<Node>& Way::GetNodesCollection() const {
return this->nodesCollection;}
```

This is getting error  "invalid initialization of reference of type ‘`std::vector<Node>&`’"
how to initialize this correctly.

Comment: Either remove `const` qualifier or return a const reference (`std::vector<Node> const &`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to return a non `const` reference to a class member from a `const` method. This is not allowed, since it would violate the semantics of `const` class member functions (which can only access a const version of `this`).

To fix your error, either write

```
const std::vector<Node>& Way::GetNodesCollection() const {
    return nodesCollection;
}
```

or

```
std::vector<Node>& Way::GetNodesCollection() {
    return nodesCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, this isn't just a "getter", because I can get the reference and then modify the contents. You want another `const` modifier:

```
const std::vector<Node>& Way::GetNodesCollection() const {
     return this->nodesCollection;
}
```